# How can I know the updated file during the gitlabci pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci

During the gitlab pipeline (triggered after each commit on my branch), I want to know which files are concerned by the commit in order to apply specific bash script regarding each file.
I'm currently using the following code in my `gitlabci.yaml` file:

```
    - export DIFF=$(git show --stat HEAD)
    - ./myBashScript.sh
```

Then I'm using `$DIFF` in my bash script.
But is there a better approach? (I'm using a local gitlab 10.8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use already [existing CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) to do something like this to retrieve the list of changed files:

```
git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

CI_BUILD_BEFORE_SHA and CI_BUILD_REF if you are [running on Gitlab 8.x](https://docs.gitlab.com/11.7/ee/ci/variables/README.html#gitlab-90-renaming)

Comment: @NicoESIEA On old versions these were CI_BUILD_BEFORE_SHA and CI_BUILD_REF. Ref https://docs.gitlab.com/11.7/ee/ci/variables/README.html#gitlab-90-renaming